# "The Rails Way" 3-rd edition proc exercise error page 360

Tags: ruby, irb, proc

I'm doing an exercise from page 360 in book "The Rails Way" 3-rd edition 11.2.5 Storing Code    as  Proc    Objects and I getting error instead of a correct output.
Code in proc.rb file

```
def greet(&block)
  block.call
  "Good morning,  everyone."
end
philippe_proc = Proc.new  { return  "Too  soon, Philippe!"  }
philippe_lambda = lambda  { return  "Too  soon, Philippe!"  }
p greet(philippe_proc)      # Too soon, Philippe!
p greet(philippe_lambda)    # Good  morning,  everyone.
```

and the output is

```
ruby proc.rb 
proc.rb:1:in `greet': wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0) (ArgumentError)
from proc.rb:7:in `<main>'
```

ruby -v
ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-linux]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
p greet(&philippe_proc)    
p greet(&philippe_lambda)
```

Blocks are special parameters. When you defined `greet` as

```
def greet(&block)
```

That & means that is not a "normal parameter" but a block, a proc, a lambda and you have to say that even when you call the method.

This because if you had a method that takes a parameter AND a block and you pass just one of them you couldn't otherwise say which of them is.

Comment: It gives me another error ruby     proc.rb 
    proc.rb:5:in `block in <main>': unexpected return (LocalJumpError)
     from proc.rb:2:in `greet'
     from proc.rb:7:in `<main>'

Comment: I believe it don't associate &philippe_proc and &philippe_lambda with Proc.new  { return  "Too  soon, Philippe!"  } and { return  "Too  soon, Philippe!"  } respectively. And & symbol can't be used as beginning of variable name.

Comment: There is a difference between a lambda and a proc if you have a return. return in a lambda returns from the block and in this case is ok. but return from a proc return from the enclosing method and in this case you have not one. This is the issue. You have no error if you try that in a method. But you are in the main scope.